# Numerical renormalization of 2D Ising lattice

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization, computational-physics, ising-model, algorithms

I'm trying to make some toy computations on the $2D$ Ising model on a square lattice. I want to apply a renormalization transformation, and try to estimate observables on the renormalized lattice using Monte Carlo. My approach is as follows until now: I know how to generate configurations of the original lattice using Monte Carlo, moreover, let $s=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,\dots\}$ be a configuration and let $s_r$ be the configuration the renormalization transformation, I know that by definition

$$ P_r(s_r)=\sum_{t:t_r=s_r}P(t)$$

where $P_r$ is the renormalized probability and $P(t)=\frac1Ze^{-\beta H(t)}$ is the initial one, so to generate configurations of the renormalized lattice I do as follows

- generate a configuration $s$ using some Monte Carlo algorithm
- apply the transformation to $s$, for example eliminate spins or take the majority vote on blocks
- measure observables on the new spins
- start over

this looks naive, but it makes sense to me, because the probability of generating any renormalized configuration $s_r$ is equal to the probability of generating any of the configurations that map to it, which is the sum of their individual probabilities. Problem is that my code doesn't produce the results I'd expect: for example, starting from below the critical temperature and measuring the magnetization per spin at each renormalization level, I would expect it to go up, since the system should be driven away from the critical point to the negative temperature region with high magnetization per spin. Instead, the magnetization per spin stays the same. The magnetization overall decreases, but that's just because there are less spins at each level.

I'm using simple decimation for now, so step 2 and 3 simply correspond to summing the spins in a sublattice.

I'm reasonably sure that the Monte Carlo updates work properly, is my expectation wrong or is my code wrong?

Comment: From what you describe, I don't see why this wouldn't work. The only explanation I have is that you are starting from a configuration which has not reached equilibrium (say, still showing coexistence of both phases). What does your starting configuration look like?

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thanks for the comment! I equilibrate for a couple thousands steps. The curious thing is that if I generate a plot of the magnetization per spin as a function of temperature for 3 levels of renormalizations (original, decimated once, decimated twice) I get three superimposed identical curves, that are what I would expect for the whole system, small above the critical temperature and high below, with a "discontinuity" at $T_C$ smoothed by the finite size, so I think that the initial configuration must be alright, as at least the non-renormalized curve is correct.

Comment: @YvanVelenik so the algorithm itself isn't wrong in some way?

Comment: At least not from my reading of your description of it :) .

Comment: @YvanVelenik should I observe the system being driven towards the low temperature phase already with a 64x64 lattice?

Comment: If you start not too close to the critical temperature, then yes (note that you need the correlation length to be substantially smaller than the system's size; otherwise, you're really inside the critical region and anything can happen).

Comment: It is true that the magnetization density in the 2d Ising model below $T_c$ very quickly approaches $\pm 1$, so you might have difficulty seeing anything. In particular, the majority spin occupies a fraction close to $1$ of the vertices in the box, so that after very few steps of applying the majority rule, I'd expect to hit the full $+$ or full $-$ configuration in your box. Maybe you could instead measure the average size of excitations (clusters of minority spins), from which you should be able to deduce some effective temperature.

Comment: Of course, starting from a larger box would allow you to start closer to the critical temperature and thus observe better the initial stages of renormalization.

Comment: @YvanVelenik I tried majority vote, and that works all right! It's a mystery to me why decimation doesn't.

Comment: You may get more help with this problem on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/#)

Comment: There is also an Ising model tag on Materials Modeling Stack Exchange.